# auto resizing sub views in iphone/ipad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autoresizingmask

I have a view(name it as "MyView") in which I have 4 subviews - say 2 UIImageView's, 2 UILabel's.I have to place this view in other view (where ever it requires).while placing MyView I have to give a frame(any frame).According to the frame given to "MyView" the subview's should get adjusted by position and size (auto adjust according to the original place and size).
If I remove any 1 of the 4 subviews from "MyView" the remaining 3 subviews should automatically get adjusted within "MyView". I should achieve this without "AutoLayout" to support the older versions.
I have used AutoresizingMask properties in IB, but didnt get the desired result.

Can anyone help me in how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Without Autolayout you can't do any suffisticated layout out of the box.

You would have to write a custom subclass for `MyView`. You then overwrite it's `layoutSubviews` (this is beeing called everytime the view's frame changes) to reposition and resize your subviews.

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *iv2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
//...
@end

@implementation MyView

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    CGRect frame = self.iv1.frame;
    frame.origin.x = someValue * self.bound.size.width;
    frame.origin.y = ...;
    self.iv1.frame = frame;
    ...
}
```